# How to share a variable across modules in Kivy

Tags: python, variables, kivy

I am trying to declare a variable in my .py file that can be used in my .kv file. I am declaring the variable in my App class and calling it in my .kv file, but I am getting an error.

Here is my .py

```
class SwitchScreenU553(Screen):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    MY_NUMBER = .8
    def build(self):
        return presentation
```

and here is my .kv

```
<SwitchScreenU553>:
    name: "switchU553"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'
    FloatLayout:
        ToggleButton:
            text: "HB"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: app.MY_NUMBER
            size_hint: 0.13,0.4
            pos_hint: {"center_x":(0.3/8)+.05, "center_y":.8}
```

When I try to use this I get the following error:

[image: AttributeError]

This seems to work for others, but I am obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

If you add `print()` function before and after the `presentation = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")`, before `MainApp().run()`, and before `return presentation`, you will notice that the *Builder.load_file()* method is executed first. At that point, *app* and *MY_NUMBER* does not exist and this resulted in *AttributeError*.

## Solution

There are two solutions and they are as follow:

1. Move `presentation = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")` to the `build()` method i.e. just before `return presentation`, or
2. Replace `return presentation` with `return Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")` and remove `presentation = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")`

## Other Errors

### kv file - No Root Widget

In *kivy.kv*, there is no ***root widget*** defined. Therefore, it will return ***None***, and no window will be displayed.

The solution is to replace class rule, `<SwitchScreenU553>:` with root rule, `SwitchScreenU553:`

### Python file - MY_NUMBER / font_size

The text's [font_size](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.text.html) is an integer and defaults to 12. Therefore, assigning *MY_NUMBER = 0.8* to *font_size* resulted in zero been assigned and no text ("HB") displayed.

The solution is to replace ***0.8*** with ***8***.

[How to load KV](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> ***Builder***: You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string or file defines a root widget, it will be returned by
>   the method:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_string(kv_string
> ```

[Kv language » Rule context](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

```
The root rule is declared by declaring the class of your root widget, without any indentation, followed by : and will be set as the root attribute of the App instance:

    Widget:

A class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between < > and followed by :, defines how any instance of that class will be graphically represented:

    <MyWidget>:
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class SwitchScreenU553(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    MY_NUMBER = 8

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### kivy.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

SwitchScreenU553:     # root rule
    name: "switchU553"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'
    FloatLayout:
        ToggleButton:
            text: "HB"
            color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: app.MY_NUMBER
            size_hint: 0.13,0.4
            pos_hint: {"center_x":(0.3/8)+.05, "center_y":.8}
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Answer (score 0):

i will try to answer your question, i don t really know kivy's language but i know something of python and global variable, first in python you need put self in your attribute, so i think you should have:

```
class MainApp(App):
self.MY_NUMBER = .8
def build(self):
    return presentation
```

and second you need to import your module"where is your class "MainApp" like:

```
#from module import MainApp
<SwitchScreenU553>:
name: "switchU553"
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'background.png'
FloatLayout:
    ToggleButton:
        text: "HB"
        color: 1,1,1,1
        font_size: app.MY_NUMBER
        size_hint: 0.13,0.4
        pos_hint: {"center_x":(0.3/8)+.05, "center_y":.8}
```

that is what i think.